# Creating a batch file that opens google chrome and puts input into the search box?

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, command-line

So I am just playing with batch files and was curious if it was possible to create a batch file that opens the google browser and without typing into the search box, a variable from my batch file gets put into the search box. Anyone know if that's possible? Thanks.

```
@echo off
cd c:\program files (x86)\google\application
start chrome.exe www.youtube.com
```

I can open the web browser, I can even change the code to store the variable, but need to know how to send that variable to the search engine. Youtube i just the website i left it at.

Comment: You play without code ?? i don't think so ?? so post what did you tried and played so far as code until now !

Comment: Never, just didn't post it. I thought it it was a given for now. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you use google as search engine, try to pass the keyword like this :

```
@echo off
start "" chrome.exe www.google.com#q=batch
```

and if you want add more than a keyword just add the sign **+**

```
@echo off
start "" chrome.exe www.google.com#q=batch+vbscript+HTA
```

Answer (score 0):

You could send [raw HTTP request](https://www.google.cz/webhp?hl=en#newwindow=1&hl=en&q=understanding%20URL) as follows:

```
start "" "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=simon's cat"
```

Below is possible approach how-to make it more readable in a batch script (non-systematic approach, as e.g. `site` variable joins together *protocol* and *host name*). Use appropriate value of `engine` variable for a particular host (as it could vary for different servers):

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "chromepath=c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" path to chrome
set "site=https://www.youtube.com"
set "engine=results?search_query"                              
set "search=simon's cat"                                       string to search
start "" "!chromepath!\chrome.exe" "!site!/!engine!=!search!"
```

[Delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) used as *any* variable in above code could contain `cmd` *poisonous* characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the simplest alternative, you can just copy the full link and paste it in:

```
@echo off
start chrome "youtube.com/results?search_query=funny+videos"
```

To open another tab, separate first address with a space and type `"google.com"` next to it.
If you want to open another browser like FireFox at the same time, type on a new line: `start firefox "stackoverflow.com"`

It'll look something like this:

```
@echo off
start chrome "youtube.com/results?search_query=funny+videos" "google.com"
start firefox "stackoverflow.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set tmp="%*"
IF %tmp% == "" (
        GOTO :query
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO :replace
    )

:replace
set url=%*
REM set url=%url: =+%
echo %url%
GOTO :search


:query
set /p url=Input search Keywords:
GOTO :search


:search
echo Search query confirmed: %*
echo Attaching to process..
tasklist /nh|findstr "chrome.exe" && start "" "chrome.exe" "? %url%"
REM tasklist /nh|findstr "chrome.exe" && start "" "chrome.exe" "www.google.com/search?q=%url%"
```

Here is the batch file I use for accomplishing this.
It will attach the search tab to an open process of chrome and search for %* arguments.
If you don't pass arguments, it will ask for some.

```
> url installing pycharm on ubuntu
```

There is a commented out method aswell that replaces spaces with '+', then searches with raw HTTP instead of the "? %url%" option.
Delete REM on line 12 and 25, and all of line 24 to switch

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
echo Welcome to my Search Engine!
echo Type 1 Keyword to Search. Use +s instead of spaces
set/p "keyw=Keyword is "
start https://www.google.com/search?q=%keyw%&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply