# How can one assign to a variable a string from the clipboard and using that string to search Google?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, search, clipboard

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407919/creating-a-batch-file-that-opens-google-chrome-and-puts-input-into-the-search-bo), the answer was

`@echo off
start "" chrome.exe www.google.com#q=batch`

What does #q= do here? I'm new to batch scripts and I am trying to pass in a string from the clipboard in the place of the word "batch" above.

I tried to assign`powershell -sta "add-type -as System.Windows.Forms; [windows.forms.clipboard]::GetText()"` to a variable and tried to pass the variable into the first script in the place of "batch".

Comment: `https://www.google.com/search?q=batch` or as above `www.google.com#q=batch`, will Google Search using the search term **batch**. As that was your only question above and is not a programming question, it is off topic for this site.

Comment: I have added the powershell tag to your question because you mentioned it, showed its code and although cmd.exe can send to the clipboard, it has no native way to retrieve from it.

Answer (score 3):

Google search URL is `google.com/search?q=`. Just add the Clipboard's content to it and append it to the browser invokation. At least `chrome.exe` and `iexplore.exe` allow URLs as an unnamed parameter.

```
$SearchTearm = [System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard]::GetText()
$GoogleSearch = "https://www.google.com/search?q=$SearchTerm"
$Browser = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'
Start-Process $Browser -ArgumentList $GoogleSearch
```

Since PowerShell 5 you can use `Get-Clipboard` instead of the .NET function.

Comment: May not be necessary, but depending on clipboard content I'd insert an `[System.Net.WebUtility]::UrlEncode()`

Comment: **Edit: Sorry, just realised, I should run it in powershell, not cmd.** I am getting an error : '$SearchTearm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. And the same for '$GoogleSearch', '$Browser', 'Start-Process'....

Comment: This does not work for multiple word strings I'm afraid.

Comment: Refer to LotPings comment to encode the spaces of your search term

Answer (score 0):

Not nessecary to use full path Navigator. There are always command saved.

Condensed (in PowerShell 5 minimum) :

For Chrome:

```
Start-Process "chrome" -ArgumentList "https://www.google.com/search?q=$(Get-Clipboard)"
```

For Internet Explorer:

```
Start-Process "iexplore" -ArgumentList "https://www.google.com/search?q=$(Get-Clipboard)"
```

For Edge:

```
Start-Process "microsoft-edge:https://www.google.com/search?q=$(Get-Clipboard)"
```

Comment: Since `Get-Clipboard` is a [Pscx](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx) cmdlet you can't presume it's presence.

Comment: Get-clipboard is include into PowerShell like i explain https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-clipboard?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Thanks for feedback, it's strange my PSVersion is `5.1.15063.608` but `gcm Get-Clipboard` tells me Source is `pscx` version `3.2.0.0`

Comment: Strange, my PowerShell version is the same, but gcm Get-Clipboard  give me a source Microsoft.PowerShell.Management and 3.1.0.0 like version

Comment: You can refer to the internal `Get-Clipboard' by fully qualify it like `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Get-Clipboard`. If two commands have the same name, the custom function is preferred.